# How do I accomplish interaction between HTML5 and C++ component in WINCE 7.0?

Tags: c++, html, cgi, windows-ce, isapi

I have a Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 based development board which has a HTTPD webserver and SQL Compact DB,

Objective: My task is to deploy few HTML5 pages and create C++ component for DB access.

Current solution : Currently we are thinking of CGI interface between HTML5 and C++ 
component, not sure if this is possible , but our vendor (where this board bought from) confirmed that WinCE can support ISAPI (much faster CGI).

I would like to know if we are in a right direction? or Is there a alternate solution to this? 
Asking this question because I came across this article in Code project about [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML[Building](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML%5bBuilding) C++ Application with HTML5] which talks about usage of Webkit and Qt.
Please let me know if I can explore as per this article. Can this work under Embedded-based environment.
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

It's one path. This article uses QT to intercept requests, so you are basically implementing your own web server

I don't know about your requirements but you may have quite some work if you wanna do it by yourself (implementing Sessions, Authentication, Http methods, SSL, etc).

In my case, I deactivated the standard HTTPD server and used [Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/products/padarn.aspx) for a C# backend and I found it to be ok, but it's not free.

I didn't spend much time looking for C/C++ servers but I believe setting up a pre-made web-server is a good path path unless that article meets your requirements.